# How to send SWFT messages to MQ on a remote server?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, swift-mt

Does anybody know how I can send SWIFT messages to MQ on a remote server?
I need to generate Swift message and to send to MQ. Should it be in body of JMS message or there should be another structure?

Comment: I think the answer depends on what the app that will be receiving this message is expecting. It is possible the downstream app expects you to wrap the swift message inside of something else such as FIX, FIXML, XML, JSON, without the benefit of knowing what the downstream that that will be reading the message you send to the "MQ on a remote server" no one can tell you what to do. As far as a JMS message is concerned, this adds some RFH2 headers and in some cases downstream apps do not expect this and you have to instruct your JMS app to send a "MQ" type message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIFT (or for that matter any application specific) data must be part of the message body. The structure or format of the data is application specific, in your case it's SWIFT format.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is not a real answer to your issue, it is in my opinion the only possible answer : contact your MQ team / admins / devs and check with them. They should provide you the relevant information (user / password, certificate, channels names, message format expected, ...)